# Love of same gender

Tags: halal-haram

If trying your best to achieve the everlasting rewards while knowing same gender love is an obvious sin, yet the heart happens to love one specific person from the same gender. No human can control the heart. If sticking to the right path and hoping for this desire to be fulfilled in jennah, is that good? Will it? ( May Allah forgive my heart for this sin)

Comment: Sticking to the right path and 'hoping' for it to be fullfilled is definitely the right thing to do but...it is going to be really hard, and at one point one will succumb.

Comment: @Sarah R u getting started with Islam? Feel you're a prior sinner? You should try to read some of descriptions of Jennah from Qur'an and try to grasp a picture of how it would be. Example Surah 55. May the creator guide us all

Answer (score 1):

salaams
Think of these desires as a test. every person will be tested in this dunyah, in one way or another, and just consider this as YOUR test. Allah SWT wants to see how you deal with this, knowing that homosexuality is haraam. IN Jannah, you wont have this desire, In Sha Allah, and i ask Allah SWT to make the tests of this dunyah easy for us and to guide us all to the right path. May Allah SWT forgive us all, and see how much you are struggling for His cause, and raise us all united in the highest level of Jannah, Amen
I honestly hope this desire is removed from your heart so this life may be easier for you, but In Sha Allah, He will see your pure intentions and help you in this life and the hereafter, Amen

Comment: Paying heed to the issue of "test" could be so profitable for us in order to being patience against the sins as you stated about the TEST. Actually I'm  so agree with you regarding "Think of these desires as a test". Since seeing it as a test would help you preventing... / God bless your for this nice answer.

Answer (score 0):

This desire will not be fulfilled in Jannah, Allah Ta'ala will remove this desire from your heart in Jannah Insha Allah and Allah may do the same here in this world too . Just keep praying to Allah Ta'ala and stay away from that person , dont think about her. Also keep yourself busy in some kind of work.
Read some islamic books by Shaykh Zulfikar Ahmad Naqshbandi DB.
If you know urdu here is a book https://archive.org/details/HayaAurPakdamniByShaykhZulfiqarAhmadNaqshbandi

Else search google for English lectures and books of Shaykh Zulfikar Naqshbandi.

Insha Allah it will help you to shift your heart from that person to Allah Subhanwata'ala

Remember One meaning of Kalima is : There is none worthy of LOVE (Affection) except Allah.

Comment: To be honest I would want this desire to be fulfilled n I feel it's a motivation for me to do more for Allah, but knowing it will be removed is sad n knowing the suffering will be removed. I understand that Alah is the one who deserves all the love n for sure he is the one who knows what I'm feeling exactly. I put my trust in him he will fulfill everything I want in jennah. I think of jennah as a place where each wish will happen n come true, even though it was forbidden in real life example:alcohol but in jennah alcohol rivers . Makes sense ya?

Comment: @Sarah, The wine in heaven is probably not wine. I searched the verses about it. In some there is only a mention about a full-cup, which is translated as a wine fulled cup in some translations and not others. In one verse, it is said that it is a cup of kâfur (a healthy plant). In another, it is said that it is a cup including ginger. In other verses, it is said that this drink doesn't give drunkenness and doesn't smell bad, in another smell good.

Answer (score 0):

I myself am lesbian because I only love women's. although I didn't act on it and I wont but I still know there is a lot of muslim women like me. all I can say is to pray and hope that in the after life that desire will be fulfilled. I realized long time ago that I will be alone in this life as I cant permit myself to act on what is considered a great sin. I love islam and I believe its part of my identity. other people who don't have to struggle like to judge and just say repent. it is not as easy as it sound.

Answer (score -1):

You should go by facts alone.

If you follow Islamic Theology, then everything in Islam is permitted unless it is categorically forbidden!
If Homosexuality is forbidden, then it is forbidden!

**Al-Baqarah 2:286 - "Allah burdens not a person beyond his scope"**

**Al-Bukhaari (2528) and Muslim (127) - The Prophet(SAS) said, “Allah has forgiven my Ummah for whatever crosses their mind so long as they do not speak of it or act upon it.**

If something is Ambiguous, or perhaps comes across as a metaphor that a fellow human is not able to explain from a clear, coherent and concise transparency, then that is all it is and Allah knows best!
What happens in Heaven, only Allah knows best!